# Sqflite Database Exception Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I asked a similar question yesterday, but I still couldn't solve my problem. I am sharing the problem as a photo. How can I solve this?[image]

I also use this function with button.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's because your strings aren't enclosed in ' or ": it's always better to wrap them to avoid errors. Try changing the query into `[...] VALUES ("erol", "bascifci", "erolbascifci@gmail.com", "testtesttest")`

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this. Can you explain with an example to be clear?

Comment: The line 47 of the code you posted should look like this: `'"${json[UserTitle.name]}", "${json[UserTitle.surname]}", "${json[UserTitle.email]}", "${json[UserTitle.password]}"';` It is quite hard to read, but I simply wrapped each `${...}` between `"`. In this way, each field will be included in quotes, and SQL will know that they are Strings and not part of the query

Comment: thanks. but ı got a another error. SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(no such table: table_name (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_name (name, surname, email, password) VALUES ('testname', 'testsurname', 'test@test.net', 'test123'), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT INTO table_name (name, surname, email, password) VALUES ('testname', 'testsurname', 'test@test.net', 'test123')' args [])

Comment: That means that `table_name` is a table that doesn't exist. You need to put in line 49 the real name of your users table.

Comment: one more mistake... i'm going to cry... SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(table Users has no column named surname (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Users (name, surname, email, password) VALUES ('fkfkkfkf', 'ıffıfkkfk', 'test1@test.net', 'test123'), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT INTO Users (name, surname, email, password) VALUES ('fkfkkfkf', 'ıffıfkkfk', 'test1@aplimax.net', 'test123')' args [])

Comment: thanks dude. I fix this. Delete app and restart debugging and its work. thanks again.